# Deploy a next.js project locally without code on the machine

Tags: node.js, github, deployment, next.js, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a Next.js Web App in combination with a node.js backend on a windows PC.
I know there are vercel and Heroku, but the application has to run even without a connection to the Internet. (My friend has a bar and he wanted a small ordersystem and I don't want him to be able to access the Code.)

I know I could just go "npm run build" --> "npm run start".
But I don't want the code locally on the machine because i am scared of plagiarism.
Is there a way to deploy this locally via Git? So the software runs on the local machine without the code beeing there?

Is it possible to create CI/CD, so it listens to new pushes on git?

Any help would be nice

Comment: `npm run build` is not supposed to be used in pair with `npm run start`. `build` command generates production-ready code in `.next` folder https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment

Comment: How can i use that Production ready code?

Answer (score 0):

Get a computer installed on the businesses’s local network, encrypt its disk, and install your app on it.

You can also automate deployments with git’s `postreceive` hook.

Comment: Ty, i installed a linux mini PC. Also, you can't automate deployments, because here in Germany, the end user usually has to accept the Update by law. So you can't just push. I need to add a listener, that sends a notification to the frontend if some updates are available.

Comment: You mean the update has to be accepted for the client or server?